# Detect a process exit in C#

Tags: c#, process

I've an application which does

`Process.Start()`

to start another application 'firefox.exe'. I want to wait till that application ends (process dies) and continue my execution (example: Show a messagebox). There may be multiple instances of the application 'firefox.exe' running at the same time.

I have try WaitForExit and HasExited, but it return true right after firefox process start, so that the Messagebox show immediately. 
How can i Show the messagebox in this situtation.

**Update 1:**
I tried this:

```
Process browser = new Process();
browser= Process.Start(@"dist\bin\firefox.exe");
browser.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
browser.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("AAAA!!!");
```

and HasExited similarly with EventRaising.

**Update 2:**

I have tried with many Simple Program like Notepad.exe, cmd.exe... All of them worked well. I think that Firefox call another process before running the main process and closing the original process. How can i bypass this problem.

Comment: Why not show the code of what you have tried with `WaitForExit` and `HasExited`, instead of just asking us to solve the problem for you. You will find this a more productive approach

Comment: You can't do this reliably without cooperation from the other program. It may be that when you launch an application, what you're actually running is a small updater app that checks the real app is up to date and then launches it, before itself exiting.

Comment: This is my code:
Process browser = new Process();
browser= Process.Start(@"dist\bin\firefox.exe");
browser.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
browser.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("AAAA!!!");

Comment: Is firefox still running?  For how long?  did you check Task manager to see if it is actually running?  I suspect firefox is closing immediately because you are not passing the correct parameters.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, it is still actually running. Everything is very smooth, but the WaitForExit didn't work. I don not know why

Comment: WaitForExit is waiting for the application to close.  Normally in Windows when an executable closes it returns a status.  You are not getting the status (the exit code).  If you go to task manager and close the application does it reach your code?  If so then firefox is not closing until the standard input commands tell it to close.

Comment: I would try the same code with some simpler program. Like Notepad. It is possible that firefox check for updates, start a new processes and lets the original process close.

Comment: @JonasH I guess as you too. But i do not know how to bypass this mechanism. Every simple program worked well, but firefox did not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be certain that no firefox instance is already running you can simply use `Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");` and use WaitForExit on these processes.

If you want to handle multiple concurrent firefox instances you have a bit of a problem since firefox manages multiple processes in its own special ways. When you start firefox it might just ask the existing firefox process to create a new window and then quit. So you would need to detect new windows and monitor when this window is closed. I do not think there is any way to accomplish what you want simply by waiting on processes, at least not without cooperation by the program.

In the end I would try to do whatever you are trying to accomplish some other way. Perhaps you can host a [webcontrol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol?view=netframework-4.8) inside the application? Or perhaps embed a copy of Firefox Portable or some other stand alone browser in your application and start that instead?

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried to Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox") but there were too many instances. I do not want to run webcontrol because it has too little feature. I'll try Firefox Portable now. I hope it help

Comment: I have tried with Firefox Portable but it also did not work.